# Why is livedata observe triggered twice?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata

I have a livedata object that I call on my fragment. First time works fine, it only tiggers just one time, but second time I enter the fragment it triggers twice and don't understand why.

This is where I call the observe:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_train_with_famous_detail, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    setupUi(view)
    (activity as TrainingWithFamousActivity).hideToolbar()
    setupListCategoryVideos(view)
    viewModel.getVideosData()
    viewModel.videosData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        //second time I enter the fragment it triggers his twice
        videoCategoryAdapter.loadItems(it)
    })
    viewModel.videoSelected?.let { loadTrainWithFamousDetailsData(it) }
}
```

And this is the method in my view model:

```
val videosData = MutableLiveData<List<DtoCelebrityResource>>()
fun getVideosData() {
    showLoader()

    trainingWithFamousUseCase
        .build(this)
        .executeWithError({
            videosData.value = it
            hideLoader()
        }, {
            hideLoader()
        })
}
```

Comment: are you sure that it is the same instance of your fragment that is receiving the LiveData twice? Is it possible that the fragment exists two-times and each instance receives the LIveData?

Comment: if you enter it a third time will it trigger three times?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever your fragment is created, you run this:

```
viewModel.getVideosData()
viewModel.videosData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    //second time I enter the fragment it triggers his twice
    videoCategoryAdapter.loadItems(it)
})
```

I'm assuming `getVideosData` is some async operation that fetches data from a database or something, in another coroutine/thread. In that case, when that method updates the `LiveData` with `videosData.value = it`, it will be *sometime later*

The next line is where you `observe` the LiveData - if it currently has a value, it will be delivered immediately, and the lambda will get run. When `getVideosData` finishes and sets a value, the observer will run **again**.

---

The reason you're not seeing this the first time is probably because your `LiveData` doesn't have an initial value (`val videosData = MutableLiveData<List<DtoCelebrityResource>>()`) so when you first `observe` it, the lambda doesn't fire. Then when the video data is set, you get the callback, so it only happens once.

But because that LiveData now has some data, and the point of a `ViewModel` is to maintain state when things like Fragments and Activities are closed, next time you open that fragment `videosData` **does** have an initial value when you first call `observe`. So you see that, and the update.

There are a bunch of ways you could approach this, but calling `distinctUntilChanged()` on `videosData` (which creates a LiveData that only pushes updates when the data has "changed" according to its `equals` function) might be enough to solve it. e.g.

```
// internal mutable version
private val _videosData = MutableLiveData<List<DtoCelebrityResource>>()
// exposed immutable version, with the "emit distinct values" transformation
val videosData: LiveData<List<DtoCelebrityResource>> = _videosData.distinctUntilChanged()
```

Answer (score 0):

put your viewModel inside **onCreate()** Method
and use **savedInstanceState**

```
...
lateinit var model:/*ViewModelClass*/
...
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    viewModel=ViewModelProvider(this)[/*ViewModel*/::class.java]
    if (savedInstanceState==null){
        viewModel.getVideosData()
    }
}

 override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    outState.putString("value","value")
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    setupUi(view)
    (activity as TrainingWithFamousActivity).hideToolbar()
    setupListCategoryVideos(view)
    //remove viewModel.getVideosData()
    viewModel.videosData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
  
        videoCategoryAdapter.loadItems(it)
    })
    viewModel.videoSelected?.let { loadTrainWithFamousDetailsData(it) }
}
```